# install4j 6.1.6 Installer remote debugging

Tags: install4j

I have generated an install4j Windows installer. I want the installer to run on a remote Windows machine and have to debug the installation process. The installed JVM is 1.8_161. I have tried several option in my vmoptions file:

```
-Xdebug
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999
```

or

```
-Xdebug 
-Xnoagent
-Djava.compiler=NONE
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999
```

Neither configuration works. The vmoptions' file name is the same as the media file's name except the extension.

I hadn't any problems with debugging earlier remote installers.

Best regards
anko

Comment: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999` is OK, you don't need  `-Xdebug`. What do you mean by it does not work? You have `suspend=n` so it will start up immediately and you have to connect from the remote machine. To check if the parameter is passed, change it to `suspend=y` and it will block at startup.

Comment: This is right, the installer starts up immediatly. On my local machine I set a remote debug configuration in the Eclipse IDE. It ist not possible to connect remotely. I also checked the netstat -a command in the remote windows command line. The port the debug process should listen to isn't displayed. I changed the debug option suspend to yes, the installer starts up immediately, too.

Comment: OK, it's about the installer. The installer does not read the vmoptions file, you have to pass `-J-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999` on the command line (note the `-J` prefix)

Comment: Thank's for your help. Starting the installer on the command line with the  debug options passed works. In recent install4j versions the installer could read the vmoptions file. But this is a workaround I can work with.

Comment: I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The installer does not read a .vmoptions file for security reasons, because installers are often saved in writable locations when they are downloaded.

You have to pass `-J-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999` on the command line (note the -J prefix)